# Mousemove events don't trigger

Tags: javascript

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll("img")
  .forEach((node) =>
    node.addEventListener("mousemove", () => console.log("move"), true)
  );
```

I don't understand why this script doesn't work on [this site](https://www.stormmanagement.com/models/women/main/). You can try yourself by copy/pasting the code in console.

I expect it to log "move" whenever I move my mouse on every image, right? What am I missing?

I need to understand **why** it doesn't work.

Comment: @BaptiseArnaud The mousemove event is attached correctly to the image but when you hover the image, `figure.photo.talent-image-crop::before` blocks the mouse from reaching the image as whenever you try to hover the image, you will see the translucent black background gets the focus. If you remove `::before` you will see the mousemove event reaches the img element.

Comment: There is no way to make it ignore `::before`?

Comment: Why don't you attach the event listener to `figure` or `a` instead?

Comment: you have no img selector. The html element used for images is figure so use that selector and you will see the move logs

Comment: Because I'm implementing a script that is not supposed to know wether there are pseudo elements. I'm not targeting this site specifically, my script is supposed to work on every site

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
document
  .querySelectorAll("img").forEach(node => node.onmousemove = function(){console.log("move")});
```

Comment: It doesn't. Test it yourself on the site I linked.

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud if you go to the bottom of your website and try my script on this image - https://www.stormmanagement.com/images/layout/cyber-essentials.png - "CYBER ESSENTIALS PLUS"
It will work.
Seems like you have a overlay on the html hierarchy of girls images...

Comment: I need to know why it doesn't work on the other img elements

Comment: As codam_hsmits  mentioned, your images are behind a link tag. So if you prefer to keep your current structure, you should use codam_hsmits specific script, if you uncover your images, you can use my generic script, which will work on any site.

Answer (score -1):

Your image is hidden behind a link tag. Therefore, your event is not propagated down to the image. Instead, try using:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll(".talent-link")
  .forEach((node) =>
    node.addEventListener("mousemove", () => console.log("move"), true)
  );
```

Comment: Yeah that is impossible as this depends on the html / css used.